# How to create a portal to the End in Creative? (Mine craft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have tried to make an End portal, I have tried-

- Placing all in different angles
- Creating a 3x3 box

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the portalframe-blocks a bit more carefully you see that they have a certain orientation.

There are two lines on the bottom and top of the frame and they have to point into the space where the portal should be. This is crucial for the portal to generate.

You also need the ender-eyes to complete it in case you forgot about that.

Here's an image how to build one:

[image: Build Schematics]